# Implementing local server in iOS

Tags: ios, server, localhost, file-transfer

I am working with offline video streaming and for this I need a local server running on local port.
I need to return a video file from local server and then play it with a player. So what is the best way to achieve this. 
If I can use any available library then please provide so links.

Here I am using CocoaHTTPServer but can not return a file, is anybody knows how to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need a local server?

Comment: My video file is in encrypted format and once its returns from server my player is decrypt's it and they play. So I need to achieve this with offline as well.

Comment: But if it's local why can't the client just read it straight from disk?  That's all the server is going to do, except that you have a redundant network connection, making it slower and much more complex.

Comment: Video files are encrypted and can't play directly on other hand player is only one can decrypt's and play it.

Comment: What is the interface to the player? Does it accept a URL, for example, where you could pass it a `file://` URL instead of `http://`?  Did you write the player?

Comment: Nope, its third party and uses http://

Comment: And have you tried passing `file://`?

Comment: Nope, I will try it but if I can implement the local server then it will be the same approach like online and will keep my coding as it is.

Comment: file:// is not working, can you suggest some libraries with can be used for local server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91465/discussion-between-raj-216-and-droppy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figure out the solution with GCDWebServer and its working fine. As per expections. From following link you can download the GCDWebserver `https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer`